# Printing characters with a pointer's function

Tags: c

```
#include "head.h"
void readText(char *buffer)
{
    char c;
    int count=0;
    char *newBuffer =(char *)calloc(SIZE,sizeof(char));
        if(newBuffer==NULL)exit(1);
    int i=1;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (count % SIZE == 0)
        {
            i++;
           newBuffer = (char *)realloc((char *)buffer,i*SIZE);
           if(newBuffer==NULL){
               printf("Not enought space, bye");
               exit(1);
           }else{
           buffer=newBuffer;
           }
        }

        if (c != '\n'){
           *buffer++ = c;
        count++;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int choose;
    char *buffer;
    printf("Please choose the desired method:\n Press 0 for buffer-method.\nPress 1 for Linked List method\n");
    scanf("%d", &choose);

    buffer = (char *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL){
        printf("Something went wrong, please try again\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    readText(buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
}
```

So I have been tasked with writing a function, that reads text and each time it passes 60 characters, i need to do realloc. Now everything works till I use called, meaning if I get more then 60 characters from the user, I get an error, and the terminal points to a problem with the realloc.
Whats the problem?

Comment: please properly format your code. have an empty line between every code line is bad. Also your indentation is inconsistent.

Comment: also turn up the compiler warnings, they will point you exactly to where the issue is with your code. Also don't cast to `void *` unless you need it. It can hide some nasty bugs. And in this case you absolutely don't need it.

Comment: Please turn up your compiler warnings. `buffer[i] = c;` This should show some warning like "making pointer from integer" as the types do no match. Also `buffer = (char *)calloc` will assign to the local copy of the address of your pointer. It will not be visible outside your function. (Additionally the cast is nonsense as the target of this assignment is not of type  `char*` but `void**`) Furthermore why would you want to define parameter `buffer` as `void**` when you want to deal with `char`? Making it `char **bufffer` would be much more straight forward.

Comment: %c? did you mean %s

Comment: I changed the function, please if you can see it again... I've added exactly what I need to do and fail to do so